# Form Designer and Namespaces

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a static event in a DLL that I use frequently - Toolkit.Dialogs.ExitConfirm

The only way I can use this event is by modifying the line that adds the event in form.Designer.cs. Example:

```
this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.Form1_FormClosing);
```

becomes

```
this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(Toolkit.Dialogs.ExitConfirm);
```

If I try to add it via the Properties->Events page, it gives me this error: 'Toolkit.Dialogs.ExitConfirm' is not a valid identifier.

Is there a way to allow Form Designer to reference events from other classes/namespaces?

Edit: some people work better with visual cues, so here's some images to define the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fsRd.jpg

The first image shows how I have to make it work in Visual Studio - an event that calls an event.

The second image shows what I'm actually trying to do.

The third image is the error that occurs when I key in the method name by hand.

Comment: Why don't you just call Toolkit.Dialogs.ExitConfirm from event handler generated by Visual Studio like this: private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) { Toolkit.Dialogs.ExitConfirm(sender, e); }

Comment: plz check that Toolkit.Dialogs.ExitConfirm method and Formclose event handler parameters are same?

Comment: The method parameters are identical. Added some images to show what I'm after in a more concise way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WinForms designer isn't designed to do that. I'm a little surprised it doesn't lose your event the next time you make a change in the designer.

A few ideas on other ways you could make this work:

- You could make a Form class that hooks the event for you, and descend all your other forms from that base class. Then you'd get the behavior everywhere.
- You could make a utility method that hooks the event for you, and call it from each form's constructor.
- You could make an extension method that hooks the event and then shows the form, and call your extension method everywhere you show your forms (instead of calling `Show`).

The base class is probably the simplest solution, as long as you aren't already using form inheritance for some other purpose.

Comment: I probably should've phrased my question better, but this was the answer I was seeking. In the end, I did make a template form that I'm using now.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a static event in a DLL

You don't, you just have a *method*.  FormClosing is the event, your method can be the *event handler method* if it has the proper signature.  The designer simply doesn't support what you try to do, you'll have to stop trying.  There are two sane solutions, both involve writing code in the form class.  First you can do it in the constructor:

```
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.FormClosing += Toolkit.Dialogs.ExitConfirm;
    }
```

Or the sane one since it doesn't make sense for a class to listen to its own events:

```
    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e) {
        Toolkit.Dialogs.ExitConfirm(this, e);
        if (!e.Cancel) base.OnFormClosing(e);
    }
```

Which has the great advantage of working properly when you derive another form from this one.  Which is also a strong hint to what you are probably really should do.  It looks like you are trying to write common code for dialogs.  The "Toolkit" namespace suggests as much.  Make it work well by having this toolkit implement a base form class instead.  Now you can design your form class without any code or event handlers:

```
public partial class Form1 : Toolkit.Dialogs.BaseDialog {
   // etc
}
```

With the assumption that Toolkit.Dialogs.BaseDialog is a class derived from Form that overrides OnFormClosing().  Maybe it should also have a public property named "ConfirmOnClose" of type bool.  which enables the "ExitConfirm" logic.  You can set *that* property in the designer without trouble.

Comment: I ended up making a template form as you suggested, was just curious if it was possible to set it up through the designer.

Answer (score 0):

You can call this Method 'Toolkit.Dialogs.ExitConfirm' On form closing event of your application form and pass required param to Toolkit.Dialogs.ExitConfirm

Comment: That's how I do it now, but I was just wondering if I could put it directly into the form designer events page, as opposed to generating an event to call an event. Somewhat defeats the aim.